# Package javax.servlet.*; does not exist, other javax package also not exist

Tags: tomcat, servlets, package

I use JDK7,JRE7 and Tomcat 7. I already mentioned the classpath of Tomcat library in command prompt. But when compiling the servlet I got an error:

> package javax.servlet does not exist

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The `servlet-api.jar` is located in dir $CATALINA_HOME/lib e.g. `d:\tomcat7\lib` so it should compile. Paste your compile error, it may indicate where the problem is.

Comment: here is the command prompt that i used,
C:\MyProjects\project1>javac -classpath "C:\ProgramFiles\ApacheSoftwareFoundation\Tomcat7.0\lib\servlet-api.jar;classes;". -d classes src\Ch1Servlet.java

and the compiler error shown after the compiling my servlet(i.e. Ch1Servlet.java),

src\Ch1Servlet.java:1: error: package javax.servlet does not exist
import javax.servlet.*;
^
src\Ch1Servlet.java:2: error: package javax.servlet.http does not exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested your example and the compiler error was shown when you have mispelling in the path.

Command:

```
javac -classpath "D:\tomcatX\lib\servlet-api.jar;classes;" -d classes src\Ch1Servlet.java
```

Error:

```
src\Ch1Servlet.java:3: package javax.servlet.http does not exist
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
```

Command:

```
javac -classpath "D:\tomcat\lib\servlet-api.jar;classes;" -d classes src\Ch1Servlet.java
```

Now it is ok.

So check carefully your path to the Tomcat (I think than it is lack of some spaces):

```
javac -classpath "C:\ProgramFiles\ApacheSoftwareFoundation\Tomcat7.0\lib\servlet-api.jar;classes;‌​" -d classes src\Ch1Servlet.java
```

Probably it should be:

```
javac -classpath "C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat7.0\lib\servlet-api.jar;classes;‌​" -d classes src\Ch1Servlet.java
```

Comment: Thank You very much @lukpaw, problem solved now with the spaces in the classpath.